# wrap overlapping x-axis of bar chart in d3 angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, bar-chart

I am working on stack bar chart whose having longer x axis overlapping each other. I have written wrap function but still facing some issue. I have created demo here=> https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-trend-bar-hp3jnc.

```
   public wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
      
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        console.log(width)
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
  }
```

what missing in code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to make linebreaks at the place of space. and in your example all the labels contain NO space.
I propose you to at least try to linebreak before the uppercaseLetter

```
words = text.text().match(/^[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+/g).reverse()
```

Comment: can we break the word according bar width?. it should not break boundary of bar width. All axis should take space according to bar width .